# Pushing local changes from current repository to completely new repo created in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have been making changes in my local for a app hosted in a repo in GitHub. Now I want to push all the change I have been adding locally to a completely new repo that I have created in GitHub. When I try to push the local changes to this completely new repo, I get error message saying:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Now, I am little hesitant to do git pull from my new repo because I suspect it will wipe out my local changes.

How should I push my changes to new repo?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to push?  It's likely that `git push --force` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @SvenMarnach I did git pull <new_repo> master and then did git push <new_repo> master. It worked. :) I guess git push --force would work with out doing pulling first right ?

Comment: Yes, using `--force` the push should ignore the state of the remote branch and simply push your branch over it regardless of whether your branch is a descendent of the remote branch.

Comment: `--force` would have "worked" but it would have blown over whatever work was on the remote with your local changes, potentially losing work.  `git pull` will not wipe out your local changes, and anything it does is reversible.  `git push --force` is not (easily) reversible. If you want to inspect what `git pull` might do you can `git fetch` and inspect the `origin/master` remote branch.

Comment: Yep, thanks @Schwern for the info, at first I was hesitant to pull but found out git pull to be safe for local changes.

Comment: @Schwerm please post an answer that can be accepted so other people passing by don't think this is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to be hesitant to do git pull `<new_repo>` master followed by git push `<new_repo>` master. This is the safest way to push changes to the remote repo. git pull doesn't wipe out local changes and anything thing it does is reversible.

Closing this thread.